# Create a WPF Visual Control with larger height than the screen-height

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control which is used as a template for printing receipts with the PrintVisual method. This is working fine but sometimes the receipt is very long. Because of the limitation of the window size, which can't become larger than the window size, the receipt is getting cut off.

Is there a way around this limitation by using other controls, or getting the window higher?

Comment: Put the UserControl in ScrollViewer. You might have to adjust your Template for scrolling.

Comment: Or even simpler, in a StackPanel.

Comment: Both solutions are awesome! Thanks! Scrollviewer is better in my case using a optional Preview